# Find the first index of a character in a string

Tags: c, string

I am supposed to loop through the character of arrays that is passed in and look for the first occurrence of char, then return the index of the first occurrence. if char is not found then I return -1. This seems to work for all characters except the character at 0, which it does not find for some reason.

```
int find_ch_index(char string[], char ch) {
    int i = 0;
    while (string[i++]) {
            if (string[i] == ch) {
                    return i;
            }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger. What is `i` the first time the if statement is reached.

Comment: That's why beginners are taught to use for-loop when there is explicit initializer, condition and iterator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should increment i at the end of the while loop:

```
int find_ch_index(char string[], char ch) {
    int i = 0;
    while (string[i]) {
        if (string[i] == ch) {
            return i;
        }
        i++
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You won't find the first char ever, because:
    while (string[i++])

Increments i from '0' to '1', so the statement at 'if' never compares the first char.

Quit this increment and do it at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

i is getting incremented to 1 from 0
 inside while loop.

Answer (score 0):

In the while condition

```
while (string[i++]) {
```

you increased index i. Thus in the next statement

```
        if (string[i] == ch) {
```

you are using the increased index.

The function can be written the following way

```
int find_ch_index( const char string[], char ch ) 
{
    int i = 0;

    while ( string[i] && string[i] != ch ) i++;

    return string[i] == ch ? -1 : i;
}
```